# Why do these simple SVGs paths have different radii?

Tags: html, web, svg

Why do these two SVG paths have two different radii, even though the radius values are all `73`? Run the code snippet to see what I mean

```css
.overflow-visible {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<div style="padding: 100px">
  <svg width="145" height="1" class="overflow-visible">
    <path d="
             M 0 0 
             A 73 73 0 0 1 140 0
             " stroke="black" fill="transparent" stroke-width="3"></path>
  </svg>

  <svg width="83" height="1" class="overflow-visible">
    <path d="
             M 0 0 
             A 73 73 0 0 1 79 0
             " stroke="black" fill="transparent" stroke-width="3"></path>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried displaying one on top of the other? They are pretty similar if you do that. I suspect this is one of those illusion problems.

Answer (score 4):

If you flip the large/sweep flags to draw the rest of the circles, you'll see that both arcs are parts of the same circle (with radius 73):

```html
<svg width="360" height="200">
    <g stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="none">
        <path d="M 20 60  a73 73 0  0 1  140 0"/>
        <path d="M220 60  a73 73 0  0 1   79 0"/>
    </g>
    <g id="the-missing-parts" stroke="lightskyblue" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="4" fill="none">
        <path d="M 20 60  a73 73 0  1 0  140 0"/>
        <path d="M220 60  a73 73 0  1 0   79 0"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```